# Why does Qiskit swap gate accept registers, but cswap doesn't?

Tags: quantum-gate, programming, qiskit

In Qiskit, I am trying to perform controlled-Swap (cswap) of two registers, but an error occurs:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, ClassicalRegister, QuantumRegister
from qiskit import execute, IBMQ, Aer

c = ClassicalRegister(1)
ancilla = QuantumRegister( 1 )
phi = QuantumRegister(4, 'phi')
psi = QuantumRegister(4, 'psi')
qc = QuantumCircuit(ancilla, phi, psi, c)
qc.h(ancilla)
qc.swap(phi, psi)
qc.cswap(ancilla[0], phi, psi)
```

The swap works, exchanging each qubit of the first register (phi) with each qubit of the second register (psi), I expected that the cswap would work in the same way but the following error occurs:

```
qiskit.qiskiterror.QiskitError: "QuantumRegister(4, 'phi') is not a tuple.A qubit should be formated as a tuple."
```

I have read [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5197/why-wont-qiskit-ccx-gate-accept-registers) but it didn't help

Comment: What version of qiskit are you running? I tested your code out in qiskit v0.11.1, and it did not give me that error. It did what was expected.

Comment: The version I am using is the same, what can be the reason?

Comment: Are all of your other qiskit versions the same? This is my list of versions: 
`{'qiskit': '0.11.1',
 'qiskit-terra': '0.8.2',
 'qiskit-ignis': '0.1.1',
 'qiskit-aer': '0.2.3',
 'qiskit-ibmq-provider': '0.3.1',
 'qiskit-aqua': '0.5.3'}`

you can get this by running `qiskit.__qiskit_version__`

Comment: I created a new environment with just qiskit 0.11.1 and now it is working ...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what y'd like to do.
But I think it's because *ancilia* does not correspond to the quantum bits that follow

> qc.cswap(ancilla, phi, psi)
> qc.draw()

[image]